Dynamic Implementation Selection in .NET Dependency Injection
i have two different implementations for a single interface that i need to register in Dependency injection, and i need to conditionally check which implementation to instantiate at a given moment.
i have used factory pattern & factory delegate and i just want to know if there's a better way to achieve this.
i will use simple objects to keep it simple
IExampleService
    internal interface IExampleService
    {
        public ExampleMode Mode { get; }
        void Show();
    }

    internal enum ExampleMode
    {
        ExampleA,
        ExampleB
    }

ExampleAService
        public ExampleMode Mode => ExampleMode.ExampleA;
        public ExampleAService()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating Example A");
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Disposing Example A");
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Example A Show");
        }

ExampleBService
        public ExampleMode Mode => ExampleMode.ExampleB;
        public ExampleBService()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating Example B");
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Disposing Example B");
        }

        public void Show()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Example B Show");
        }

what is the appropriate way to achieve conditional implementation selection on dependency injection.
i have used two different implementations of factory pattern, the first one takes an Ienumerable<IExampleService> so the services are instantiated by the DI and follow the assigned service lifetime registered, but i want to avoid the overhead of instantiating all the implementations just to select one.
to solve this i used another factory variant where i manually instantiate the required service but now i have to make sure that i dispose this object manually and these services no longer comply to the service lifetime registered.
ExampleServiceFactory
    internal class ExampleServiceFactory : IExampleServiceFactory
    {
        private readonly IEnumerable<IExampleService> exampleServices;

        public ExampleServiceFactory(IEnumerable<IExampleService> exampleServices)
        {
            this.exampleServices = exampleServices;
        }

        public IExampleService GetExampleService(ExampleMode mode)
        {

           //Using DI to inject Ienumerable of services
            return exampleServices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Mode == mode);



            //Manually instantiate Services
            //return mode switch
            //{
            //    ExampleMode.ExampleA => new ExampleAService(),
            //    ExampleMode.ExampleB => new ExampleBService(),
            //    _ => throw new NotSupportedException(),
            //};
        }
    }

and injecting an IServiceProvider to the factory made perfect sense to me but it seems to be an anti-pattern

Another service locator variation to avoid is injecting a factory that resolves dependencies at run time. Both of these practices mix Inversion of Control strategies.

currently iam using a factory delegate to conditionally instantiate the required implementation and pass it to a wrapper that i can freely inject to other pages,controller,etc.
Program.cs
builder.Services.AddKeyedSingleton<IExampleService,ExampleAService>("ExampleA");
builder.Services.AddKeyedTransient<IExampleService,ExampleBService>("ExampleB");
builder.Services.AddTransient<IExampleServiceFactory,ExampleServiceFactory>();

builder.Services.AddTransient<ConfigurationProvider>();
//var exampleMode = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Device"];

builder.Services.AddTransient<IGenericExampleService, GenericExampleService>((ctx) =>
{
    var configProvider = ctx.GetRequiredService<ConfigurationProvider>();
    var exampleMode = configProvider.GetExampleMode();
    var service = exampleMode switch
    {
        ExampleMode.ExampleA => ctx.GetRequiredKeyedService<IExampleService>("ExampleA"),
        ExampleMode.ExampleB => ctx.GetRequiredKeyedService<IExampleService>("ExampleB"),
        _ => throw new InvalidOperationException()
    };
    return new GenericExampleService(service);
});


The delegate approach is golden

From your last example it becomes clear that there is no need to switch implementations dynamically, because you are loading the ExampleMode from the config and only an application restart would could change that value.
I, therefore, propose this simpler solution:
var mode =
    Enum.Parse(typeof(ExampleMode), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Device"]);

if (mode == ExampleMode.ExampleA)
{
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IExampleService, ExampleAService>();
}
else
{
    builder.Services.AddTransient<IExampleService, ExampleBService>();
}

Because at runtime there is always just one IExampleService implementation needed, you can just register that one, and let consumers depend on IExampleService directly. There is no need for a factory and no need for injecting IEnumerable<IExampleService>.

injecting an IServiceProvider to the factory made perfect sense to me but it seems to be an anti-pattern

Using a factory can make perfect sense, but do read this. The anti-pattern you are referring to is called Service Locator. It is an anti-pattern and should be prevented. But not all dependencies on IServiceProvider are implementations of the Service Locator anti-pattern. As long as the implementation that depends on the IServiceProvider (your ExampleServiceFactory) is encapsulated inside the Composition Root, its usage is fine. To understand the difference, please read this.

the config file just resembles an external configuration provider for the sake of the example this was the simplest thing that came to me. but actually the switching need to be dynamic, i.e each time i visit the capturePage the current configuration should be evaluated and an implementation is chosen based on that.
i will edit the example to clarify that

In that case, take a close look at my note about depending on the IServiceProvider not being an anti-pattern, per se, because I believe this is where your answer lies. Create a factory, which abstraction is defined in the application layer, while its implementation is defined in the Composition Root. It can depend on the IServiceProvider to resolve the required component based on the enum value. You can use keyed registrations if that simplifies things, but that's not required.
